# Is it possible to add notes with inverted stems on the same beat in Guitar Pro 6

Tags: sheet-music, drum-kits, guitar-pro

I am writing a drum-kit sheet and I would like to add two notes on the same beat with opposite stems like this

[image] and also [image]

And so far, I haven't found how to do it, I only get this kind of stuff :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [multi-voice](https://support.guitar-pro.com/hc/en-us/articles/200633951-Video-GP6-editing-Multiple-voice-edition) feature.

On each track, you can use up to 4 independent voices : the notes can have different duration and independent stem direction.

[image: Multi-voice editing]

Each number represent a voice (when selected, the notes on that voice are in black, the others in gray) and the last button displays all voices in black.
When you edit / enter notes, it is applied to the current selected voice.

Comment: Awesome ! Thank you very much. Is it possible to move note from one "voice" to another ?

Comment: Yes, there is an option in the tools menu I think (can't check now)

Comment: Tools -> Move/Swap voices